# C programming: translated function from MATLAB to C gives slightly (but significantly) different result

Tags: c++, c, matlab, precision, floating-accuracy

I have been trying to translate some MATLAB code into C but one particular function is giving me different results between the two languages. I don't think it is a precision error because the values of the variables aren't astonishingly big or small. I will post code now and then provide information about the values of the variables:

Preproccesor directives (this file is linked):

```
#include "ff_addfunc.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//#include <complex.h> (already included in the header file)
#include <math.h>
#ifndef HBAR
#define HBAR 1
#endif
#ifndef SPRING_CONST
#define SPRING_CONST 1
#endif
#ifndef PI
#define PI 3.14159265359
#endif
```

Immediately below is the problem function in C and below that is the same function in MATLAB. All numerical results match between the two before this function is called. What I find is when `x1 == x2`, MATLAB and C agree on the result; but when `x1 != x2`, C returns a slightly different result of which I will show below. This means that the arithmetic to the left of the minus sign is causing the problem.

Here is the C code:

```
double lagrangian(double x1,double x2,double dt,double m) {
    return 1/2*m*(x2-x1)*(x2-x1)/dt/dt-SPRING_CONST*(x2*x2+x1*x1)/4;
}
```

Here is the MATLAB equivalent:

```
function L = Lagrangian(x1,x2,dt,m)

k = 1;
L = 1/2*m*(x2-x1).^2./dt.^2-k*(x2.^2+x1.^2)/4;
```

What I find is if I have `x1 = -4`, `x2 = -3.986667`, `dt = 0.049087`, and `m = 1` the C function returns `-7.973378` while MATLAB gives me `-7.9365`. Now, the reason why I am putting this down as a problem in C rather than MATLAB is because I was able to verify the MATLAB number using google as a calculator.

I compiled using gcc since g++ was complaining at me for using `#include<complex.h>` instead of `#include<complex>`.

Could anyone tell me why this is and how I can correct it? If there are any questions or if you need to see more code, let me know.

Other notes (none resulting in a change):

- I tried this on linux and on OS X (two different systems)
- Tried `pow()` instead of `(x2-x1)*(x2-x1)`
- Put the numbers into the C and MATLAB functions directly to account for any rounding in the displayed numbers I printed out
- Printed out every input to make sure they were the same and checked that the correct data types were used

Comment: Doesn't matlab have a to-C compiler component? Besides, floating point types in C are not accurate, and are prone to accumulate much error after arithmetic operations especially divisions. Also, use `1.0/2.0`

Comment: Long story short, don't use native C floating points to do accurate scientific calculation.

Comment: It's almost certainly a difference in floating point precision.  My guess is the c version is using single-precision, while the matlab version is using double-precision.

Comment: it says in plain text that he's using double precision floating points

Comment: Obvious starting point: change `1/2` to `1.0/2.0`. IMO, you should probably post the formula (in normal mathematical notation) you're trying to implement, so we can verify that your C code does so correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses everyone. Jerry's advice worked and now  the values are consistent. I am curious, though, why this would matter. If left to its own devices, `1/2 = 0` in integer division the rest of the equation must cause the program to backtrack but it results in lower accuracy. Why is this?

Comment: This is your problem, but you don't need to `#define` pi. It's defined in [math.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/math.h.html) (along with any other useful constants), which you already include: `M_PI` (=3.141592653589793238462643). Note that your value of pi is not numerically equal (in double precision) to `M_PI` or the `pi` constant in Matlab. This could conceivably cause issues and is another reason to use these pre-defined constants.

Answer (score 1):

I used:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#ifndef HBAR
#define HBAR 1.0
#endif
#ifndef SPRING_CONST
#define SPRING_CONST 1.0
#endif
#ifndef PI
#define PI 3.14159265359
#endif

double lagrangian(double x1,double x2,double dt,double m) {
    return 1.0/2.0*m*(x2-x1)*(x2-x1)/dt/dt-SPRING_CONST*(x2*x2+x1*x1)/4.0;
}

int
main(void)
{
    printf("l: %g\n", lagrangian(-4,-3.986667,0.049087,1));
    return 0;
}
```

and got:

```
l: -7.93649
```

I think your non-`double`constants are goofing up your calculation.  In fact just replacing

```
1.0/2.0*m...
```

with

```
1/2*m...
```

reproduced your erroneous value for me.

Comment: Multiplication by `1/2` in question... oops.  That definitely would make a big difference.

Comment: Still shows that the use of floating point types is introducing an error though compared to MATLAB, which is probably using fixed point types of some sort. Bottom line, don't use floating point types in C/C++ if you want to do accurate numerical calculations.

Comment: displayed with different  precision

Answer (score 1):

In C, `/` and `*` have equal precedence and associate left-to-right.  This means that in this subexpression:

```
1/2*m*(x2-x1)*(x2-x1)/dt/dt
```

the subexpression `1/2` is grouped.  Because both `1` and `2` are `int` constants, this is an integer division - which is truncating.  `1/2` is always just zero in C, so this entire subexpression becomes zero.

Use `1.0/2.0` (or just `0.5`) instead.

Answer (score 1):

The direct translation would be:

```
0.5*m*(x2-x1)*(x2-x1)/(dt*dt)-SPRING_CONST*(x2*x2+x1*x1)/4;
```

(Fixed integer division and grouping of the `dt` terms)